# Does LIMIT preserve the Sort Order in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I read the documentation @ http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html, but could not understand if LIMIT works before or after the ORDER BY clause.

So if my SQL is:

```
SELECT date(event_time) as ct, jobName 
FROM events
WHERE jobName = "MY_TEST_JOB"
ORDER BY event_time DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Will the result set include the most recent 10 events, or will the limit apply before the sorting operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` is applied after the `ORDER BY`, so you will get the first 10 records sorted by `event_time` (in ascending order, so the 10 "oldest" events).

If you're trying to get the 10 *newest* events, you would just change your `ORDER BY` to:

```
ORDER BY event_time DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I have also edited the question to be more specific about sort order. +1

Comment: That doesn't really affect my answer.  `LIMIT` is applied after `ORDER BY`, so your query, as currently written, will give you the 10 most recent events.  Do you have another question I'm not seeing?